# Queue to manage function calls

Tags: java, asynchronous, queue

Hey guys I am stuck in a critical problem. I created a Dashboard of application. The data which i am displaying on Dashboard is created on the basis of my business logic. There are various **Asynchroneous triggers** that refresh this data. These Triggers are called based on different parameters.. e.g. Timer trigger, Entity Deleted, Entity Added. All these triggers have different functions which update the Data of Dashboard **(Remember this data is stored oin Database i.e. I display data on dashboard reading directly from database)** . **Calculation for the Dashboard data take some time**. 
Now my problem is that whenever two different triggers are called at the same time they created in-consitency in the data. e.g. one trigger change the data and other also reset it.. so at the end i won't get the desire result.  Now i want to make it sure that at one time only one trigger must be updating data while other one is waiting for first one to complete.

Simply what i want is to keep function calls in a **queue** and if there is already some method being executing then wait for its completion and call the next method in the queue.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) configured with a single thread. Simply submit each Runnable and the executor will queue these for execution. See [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104420/sequential-event-processing-via-executorservice) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix you can wrap each trigger in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` call that will put the task in a queue and execute it in a serial manner.

Using UI queue does make sense since your Dashboard is a UI component.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Dashboard Data updation logic in a block of code and take a Lock on that block. As various triggers happen they will automatically wait for the Lock in synchronous manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExecutorService executorService2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

It queues the jobs and process one by one